# How to get the flag/state of current operation in Odoo 9?

Tags: python, web, odoo

I am new in odoo, I want to know how we get the current flag/state of every operation.

For example: when we create a new record how do we know the current flag/state is "add"? or when we view a record how do we know the current flag/state is "view"?

It something like current user id that stored in session named "uid", is there something similar to get the current flag/state in every operation?

Comment: i don't really get what you mean by `current state/flag` is it something you defined in a model?

Comment: Actualy I tried to change scenario of my class that I asked in previous thread about get_state. I was frustrated that time but it solved by your your answer finally, thanks @danidee

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 'flag/state'.

What you are probably trying to say is that you want to know which operations are taking place on a record. The easiest method is to take a look at your log. There will be statements there in the form `/web/dataset/call_kw/model/operation` where model is your ORM model and operation could be a search, read, unlink etc. RPC calls are logged in there as well. The format of the log output is a little bit different between different versions of odoo. You can go to a lower level by monitoring sql transactions on postgresql but I do not think that this is what you want.